# Is there an api for youtube ads?

Tags: youtube-api, ads, google-ads-api

I'm looking for a way to manage ads on youtube api. Is there a way for that? I found only adwords api. Can it be used for ytb ads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use AdWords API for Youtube Ads.

Comment: Please clarify if this is accurate, given the response below. Can Adwords API can be used for YouTube targeting?

Answer (score 11):

There's currently no API to create Ads on Youtube. Adwords API does not allow you to create Video Campaigns, so the accepted answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

Youtube Video ad campaign metrics are available for retrieval in the Google Ads API. However, video campaigns cannot be mutated at all from the API, including simple operations such as pausing or enabling as well as complex operations like organizing, changing criteria, or adding ad groups.

For mutating Youtube ads, you can use Google Ads Scripts, but that too can't create a new campaign.
For creating a new youtube ad campaign, a user must use Google Ads UI as of today.