# how do I programmatically place ads on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-ads-api

How can I **programmatically** place ads on YouTube? Specifically, I am interested in targeting specific channels and videos relevant to our product niche.

Reading about some of the previous posts, there seems to be [conflicting information about adwords api and no api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243986/is-there-an-api-for-youtube-ads) etc., just confused with all this.

Could someone help out a newbie?

Answer (score 0):

To put ads on YouTube, go to https://www.youtube.com/ads/. You can learn more here and click the "Start Now" button in the top right corner to begin the process of creating an ad. You will select or upload the video you wish to be in your ad, select the locations where you want to show your ad and define the types of people you want to reach, and set how much you would like to spend on your campaign. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for responding, but my question on how to do it programmatically.

Comment: @Santino What do you mean?

Comment: I mean, your answer was on using the UI to place ads, my question was on how to use the Ads API to place ads on YouTube.